# AS3 - How to use pixel/point detection with mouse event instead of object detection

Tags: actionscript-3

This seems like it should be so easy that I'm embarrassed to ask, but I just can't get it.

I have a large round MovieClip (being used as a button). This MovieClip contains a **PNG with a transparent background** inserted into the MovieClip. 
Due to its size there are large empty registration areas on the 4 corners (the bounding box).

How can I have the mouse register as being over only the circle pixels and not the blank space (of Alpha channel pixels) in the square boundary box?

Simple sample code:

```
public function simpleSample () : void
{
    mc1.buttonMode = true;
    mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doStuff);
}

public function doStuff (event:MouseEvent) : void
{ 
    mc2.gotoAndStop(2); 
}
```

Comment: I am aware of hitTestPoint, but not sure how to implement it with an event listener and mouse coords...

Comment: By default, mouse detection is pixel based, not bounding based. Do you have something transparent in those "empty" areas? A bitmap?

Comment: Nope - just empty / transparent space.

Comment: @Aaron, imagine the Asker has a PNG image of a red circle on transparent background, how to get a `mouse_over` state _only on red pixels_  is the real question...

Comment: @jdfinch3 I see you updated to mention that you have a bitmap. An actual circle (vector) would have worked. There are a few solutions to your problem, but probably the easiest is to use an actual vector circle and set it to be the `hitArea` of the `MovieClip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 3 different ways to accomplish this.

**EDIT** Since you've later explained that your button is an image, this first option won't work for you

1. If the shape flag on `hitTestPoint` works with your button (eg it's a shape), you can use `hitTestPoint` inside your mouse click handler to figure out if the click is actually over the object:

   ```
   public function doStuff(event:MouseEvent){
       //only continue if hit test point is true,  
       //the x and y values are global (not relative to the mc your testing as one might suppose)
       //the third parameter should be true, so it takes into account the shape of object and not just it's bounds
       if(mc1.hitTestPoint(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY, true)){
           mc2.gotoAndStop(2);
       }
   }
   ```
2. If the above doesn't work because you have bimtap data in your button, then an easy way to accomplish this is to just add a shape mask to the button.

   So, either inside your button using FlasPro, mask everything with a circle shape, or, do it via code by doing the following when you first show the button:

   ```
   var s:Shape = new Shape();
   s.graphics.beginFill(0);
   s.graphics.drawCircle(mc1.x + (mc1.width * .5), mc1.y + (mc1.height * .5), mc1.width / 2);
   addChild(s);

   mc1.mask = s;
   ```
3. If using an image as the button, or you want to set a threshold of how transparent to consider a click, then you can check the transparency of the pixel under the mouse:

   ```
   function doStuff(event:MouseEvent){
       //only continue if pixel under the mosue is NOT transparent

       //first, you need a bitmap to work with
       //if you know for sure the position of your bitmap, you can do something like this:
       var bm:Bitmap = mc1.getChildAt(0) as Bitmap; 

       //annoyingly though, FlashPro makes timeline bitmaps shapes, 
             //so the above won't work UNLESS you take your bitmap in the FlashPro Library
             //and export it for actionscript, giving it a class name, then it will be an actual bitmap on the timeline.

       //As an alternative, you could (very CPU expensively) draw the whole button as a bitmap 
       var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc1.width,mc1.height,true,0x00000000);
       bmd.draw(mc1);
       var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);

       //we get the 32bit pixel under the mouse point
       var pixel:uint = bm.bitmapData.getPixel32(bm.x + event.localX,bm.y + event.localY);

       //then we grab just the Alpha part of that pixel ( >> 24 & 0xFF ).
       //if the value is 0,  it's totally transparent, if it's 255, it's totally opaque. 
       //for this example, let's say anything greater than 0 is considered good to be a click
       if((pixel >> 24 & 0xFF) > 0){

           mc2.gotoAndStop(2);

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you describe your button?  is it an image?  shape?

Comment: It's a png with a transparent background inserted into a MovieClip.

Comment: So would get `getPixel32` return a `0 / False` if on transparent pixels and a `1++ / True` if on coloured pixels? Im probably over thinking here but am worried about alpha channel having `FF` value which leads to a `True`??

Comment: The return value is a 32bit color.  It will return `0` if 100% transparent.   You could add more math in and accept a range of transparency (like tolerate up to 10% transparent etc), but then you have to do a lot more work parsing the alpha part of the return value

Comment: @VC.One - I'm not an expert on bitmap data, but every png I've worked with reports `0` with a 100% transparent pixel.  I suppose to be safe you could do `if((getPixel32(...) >> 24 & 0xFF) < 255`).

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis, thanks I get what you mean. I am satisfied with `It will return 0 if 100% transparent.`