# Actionscript 3.0 MovieClip collisions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a project with a pie containing for example 8 pieces. The pie is a MovieClip and every piece is a MovieClip as well. So a circle with 8 pieces.

[image]

```
pie_mc.piece1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fadeout);
pie_mc.piece2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fadeout);
pie_mc.piece3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fadeout);
pie_mc.piece4_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fadeout);
pie_mc.piece5_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fadeout);
pie_mc.piece6_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fadeout);
pie_mc.piece7_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fadeout);
pie_mc.piece8_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fadeout);
```

What happens is that when I click on `piece1_mc`, some of the area of the bitmap image is overlapping `piece1_mc` and then this piece is fading instead of `piece1_mc`.

Comment: "What happens is that when I click on piece1_mc, some of the area of the bitmap image is overlapping piece1_mc and then this piece is fading instead of piece1_mc." -- Did you mean to say something else here? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Put a transparent button inside each clip and have action on it, movie clip could be problem because it will have rectangular click area as you have bitmap inside it

Comment: @Snukus, I mean: What happens is that when I click on piece1_mc, some of the area of the bitmap image is overlapping piece2_mc and then this piece is fading instead of piece1_mc."

Comment: @Sameer Jain I will give it a trie although it will be lot of work...

Comment: Please see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31952016/1457439- the easiest way is to just put a mask on your movie clip that matches the pie wedge shape.

Comment: There's this one too:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30961458/1457439

Comment: Are your graphics vector shapes or bitmap graphics (png/jpeg/gif)?  If the former, there's a pretty easy way to do it.

Comment: masking also a good way as suggested by @BadFeelingAboutThis but both, mask or button, require you to draw a pie shape in flash.

Comment: @Sameer Jain I followed your suggestion and it works fine. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmaps hit area are always the full rectangle regardless of transparent areas. Probably the easiest way to solve this is to set the `hitArea` of each MovieClip to a pie shape:

1. Draw a pie shape and convert it to a symbol.
2. Place an instance of the pie shape in each MovieClip and position (rotate) it correctly.
3. Give the pie instance a name like `pieShape`.
4. Put the code `hitArea = pieShape` in the MovieClip. This will make the pie shape the area that the mouse interacts with.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I will give your suggestion a trie, by the next pie with 12 pieces and let you know how it worked.

Comment: What worked is the following. Make a button with the shape of the pie or a circle matching the upper part, where the user is likely to click on. Put the button on top of the bitmap in the movie clip symbol. Then put all the pieces in the pie, which is a Movie Clip as well. Put this on the timeline in the scene. Now when the user clicks a piece of the pie, it works. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: @Henrique Yeah, that would work, it's basically the same thing as this answer only some extra "weight" -- you don't need a whole button, just a hit area.