# How to detect collisions between bitmap and a point

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a bitmap, which has transparent areas. I have roughly worked out that if I got the BMP data from the bitmap (I know how to do), I could detect collisions between that and a point. How exactly would I detect this?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel32()

Comment: You could look at the third option of this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951954/as3-how-to-use-pixel-point-detection-with-mouse-event-instead-of-object-detect/31952016#31952016  - the getPixel32 method is where you pass in the point.  Then you check that pixel for transparency